# How to pass List<MyCustomClass> from view to controller if it is not a form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Search page that is **not** a form, and it is simplified to the following.

My model is as follows:

```
public class SearchCategory
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<SearchCategory> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, my ActionLink is as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Displaytext", "Search", "Explore", new { category = "SomeValue", categories = Model.Categories }, null)
```

My Controller's ActionResult is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Search(string category, List<SearchCategory> categories)
{
    SearchViewModel SearchModel = new SearchViewModel();
    if (category == null) { SearchModel.Category = "All Entries"; } else { SearchModel.Category = category; }

    if (SearchModel.Category == "All Entries")
    {
        SearchModel.Categories = new List<SearchCategory>();
    }
    else
    {
        SearchModel.Categories = categories;
    }

    SearchCategory c = new SearchCategory();
    c.Category = SearchModel.Category;
    if (SearchModel.Category != "All Entries")
    {
        if (SearchModel.Categories.Contains(c))
        {
            //do nothing, because the categories list already contains this category
        }
        else
        {
            SearchModel.Categories.Add(c);
        }
    }
    return View(SearchModel);
}
```

Within my controller's `ActionResult`, I am adding items to the `categories` list, and I am able to see this as a populated list if I put a breakpoint on the `ActionLink` when it re-enters the view. My problem is that the `ActionResult` receives a null instead of the populated list passed from the view when it re-enters the controller.

What am I doing wrong? Do I absolutely need to set this search page up as a form, or is there some way to get the view to pass the populated list back to the controller?

Comment: The View(categories) where categories are never populated. Should it return View(SearchModel)?

Comment: What version of mvc you are using? I am not sure that all versions support it out of the box, but lists can be send with query strings in format categories[0] =… or use a custom provider https://www.strathweb.com/2017/07/customizing-query-string-parameter-binding-in-asp-net-core-mvc/. Note old mvc had something similar to this.

Comment: @ThaiAnhDuc my bad - I updated my code above to correct this

Comment: @FilipCordas MVC 4. I considered using a string array instead, but I want to see what else people might suggest.

Comment: Are you considering on using ajax request?

Comment: @Keith i want to see if i can do it without relying on javascript/related.

Answer (score 0):

Good question...
you have to deal with strings (not a class) cause ASP.NET doesn't convert it  to standard HTTP GET Request

I made an example. 
Notice this "categories.categories[@i].Category"
[image: show]
classes

```
public class SearchCategory
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
    public class SearchViewModel
{
    public List<SearchCategory> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Method

```
        public ActionResult Search(string category, SearchViewModel categories)
    {
        if (categories == null) categories = new SearchViewModel { };
        if (categories.Categories == null) categories.Categories = new List<SearchCategory>();
        if (category != null) categories.Categories.Add(new SearchCategory { Category = category }); // add category to the list
        return View(categories);
    }
```

Here is View

```html
@model WebApplication6.Models.SearchViewModel
@using WebApplication6.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<form>
    @{
        int i = 0;
        if (Model.Categories != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
            {

                <input type="hidden" name="categories.categories[@i].Category" value="@item.Category" />
                i++;
            }
        }
        <input type="hidden" name="category" value="Abdallah Hiekal" />
        <input type="submit" name="Click me!" />
    }
</form>
<!--print-->
@if (Model.Categories != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
    {
        <div>
            @item.Category
            <hr />
        </div>
    }
}
<!--end print-->


<h2>Index</h2>
@Model.Categories.Count()
```